# How to get the values from this json url?

Tags: java, android

I would like to access the data associated under the current dates of this json link. For instance, for the date : "2020-09-26",i would like to access the revenue associated under that date. I tried researching my question but i have not found anything helpful. Could someone assist me with this? So far, i already downloaded the json data and parsed it as well as extracted the revenue and date from the json file but i would like to get the revenue under each specified date.

https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/income-statement/AAPL?limit=120&apikey=demo

```
   private void downloadAnalystEstimateData(String api) {


        // Initialize a new JsonArrayRequest instance
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                api,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        // Do something with response
                        //mTextView.setText(response.toString());

                        //Log.i("jsonResponse", response.toString());

                        // Process the JSON
                        // Loop through the array elements
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            // Get current json object

                            try {
                                 stockDetails = response.getJSONObject(i);

                               // Log.i("analyst estimate data..", stockDetails.toString());

                                 dates = stockDetails.getString("date");
                                 revenue = stockDetails.getString("revenue");

                                 Log.i("revenue", revenue);

                                Log.i("dattes", dates);





                                // Log.i("estimatedRevenueLow", estimatedEbitdaLow);


                                //Log.i("revenueGrowth", estimatedRevenueLow);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Do something when error occurred


                      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        Log.i("error", error.toString());

                        // Toast.makeText(Analyze_Stocks_Activity.this, "An error occured....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
        );



        // Add JsonArrayRequest to the RequestQueue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
```

Comment: So you're receiving dates by follow code `dates = stockDetails.getString("date");` ?

Comment: Yes i am, but i would like to get the revenue under each specific date